# Transitioning from SQLalchemy to psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I've been using Flask with SQLAlchemy but I've transitioned to using psycopg2 to insert and return values from my databases.  I was wondering how the classes in my Model.py and db object should change now that I'm no longer using SQLAlchemy.  Do I even need these anymore?

Setting up a db object:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True
db.SQLALCHEMY(app)
```

A sample of a class in my Model file:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    zipAddress = db.Column(db.String(64))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to use postgresql instead sqlite right? If yes then you just need to change `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql uri` thats it. 
Already if you dont want use at it all then you need to setup your psycopg2
settings. But I suggest to use `SQLAlchemy`. You can keep use `posgresql` for saving data and if you want to continue with sqlalchemy you can't delete that file(Models.py) and db instance.
With sqlalchemy you can easily made change on your tables and add new tables if you want.
And last thing It doesnt mean you can't use postgresql when using sqlalchemy. SQLalchemy just a framework and makes code base works for `sqlite`, `mysql`, `postgresql` for all of those you just need change the `DATABASE_URI` then it will create table for you. 
I recommend to check [flask-sqlalchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/)

Comment: Thats right.  I'm not sure whether I should continue using SQLAlchemy though since I already have my postgres table created.  I know SQLAlchemy creates databases based on the classes in my Model.py, so is that file necessary anymore?  Also is there a purpose for having a db object if I'm not using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Thank you for that.  What is the major benefit that SQLAlchemy provides if I use it with postgresql and psycopg2.

Comment: @Brosef SQLAlchemy is one more software layer that will bring more complexity than it is worth. Just throw it away and use proper SQL.